# Why use os.getenv() in settings.py for a Python Flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I forked this app:  https://github.com/cyrilrbt/canadian-nutrient-file/blob/master/cnf/settings.py

You can see there in `settings.py` and below it's using `DEBUG = (os.getenv('CNF_DEBUG', 'True') == 'True')`
I activated my conda env in the terminal and entered command after activating iPython console:

```
'CNF_DEBUG' in os.environ
```

which is `False`.

The rest of `settings.py` looks like:

```
import os
import datetime
from urllib.parse import urljoin

APP_NAME = "cnf"
APP_SYSTEM_ERROR_SUBJECT_LINE = APP_NAME + "system error"

#Flask Settings
CSRF_ENABLES = True

ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
# looks like a trick to get it to select default True == True
DEBUG = (os.getenv('CNF_DEBUG', 'True') == 'True')
TESTING = (os.getenv('CNF_TESTING', 'True') == 'True')
FLASK_DEBUG = DEBUG
FLASK_BIND = os.getenv('CNF_BIND', 'localhost')
FLASK_PORT = int(os.getenv('CNF_PORT', 8888))
ROOT_URL = 'http://' + FLASK_BIND + ':' + str(FLASK_PORT) + '/'

TEMPLATE_FOLDER = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'cnf', 'templates')
STATIC_FOLDER = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'cnf', 'static')

MONGODB_HOST = os.getenv('CNF_MONGO_HOST', 'localhost')
MONGODB_PORT = int(os.getenv('CNF_MONGO_PORT', 27017))
MONGODB_DB = os.getenv('CNF_MONGO_DB', 'cnf') # name of db

#encryption, cryptographically signs client-side cookies so they cannot be tampered with
#if tampered, session becomes invalid, insecure not to be used production
SECRET_KEY = 'this key is not secure so be careful until it is'

# Flask-User Settings
# from https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_settings.html
USER_APP_NAME = "cnf"
USER_ENABLE_EMAIL = False  # register with email
USER_ENABLE_CONFIRM_EMAIL = False # force users to confirm email
USER_ENABLE_USERNAME = True  # enable username authentication
USER_REQUIRE_RETYPE_PASSWORD = False  # simplify register form
USER_EMAIL_SENDER_NAME = 'nobu'
#USER_EMAIL_SENDER_EMAIL = 'nobu.kim66@gmail.com' # set up Flask Mail for this
USER_ENABLE_CHANGE_USERNAME = True
USER_ENABLE_CHANGE_PASSWORD = True
USER_ENABLE_FORGOT_PASSWORD = True
#USER_ENABLE_REGISTER = True
USER_ENABLE_REGISTRATION = True
USER_ENABLE_REMEMBER_ME = True
USER_AFTER_LOGIN_ENDPOINT = 'main.member_page'
USER_AFTER_LOGOUT_ENDPOINT = 'main.home_page'


# Flask-Mail settings
# For smtp.gmail.com to work, you MUST set "Allow less secure apps" to ON in Google Accounts.
# Change it in https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps (near the bottom).
MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_USE_SSL = False
MAIL_USE_TLS = True
MAIL_USERNAME = 'nobu.kim66@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD = "..."
#ADMINS = ['"Admin One" <admin@gmail.com>,]

# Sendgrid settings
#SENDGRID_API_KEY='place-your-sendgrid-api-key-here'
```

As noted in the comments above, I thought it might just be a trick instead of using comments but what other reasons are there for doing this?  And where can I find `CNF_TESTING` and `CNF_DEBUG`?
It is also doing it for the `ROOT_URL`'s `FLASK_BIND` and `FLASK_PORT`.

Comment: Using the environment to configure deployment types is a part of good design as laid out in the "12 Factor App" https://12factor.net/config

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are environment variables.

There are many advantages to writing env vars, among them easier container setup, easier and standardized access to configuration (even between programs) and better scaling.

For more information about environment variables, see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) or [12-factor](http://12factor.net/config) per @flakes suggestion.